# Is there a way to use mps-extensions via Gradle?

Tags: mps

I see https://github.com/JetBrains/MPS-extensions publishes releases via GitHub, however it does not look convenient for integration of the artifacts to a MPS-based project.

What if my project is built via MPS and it depends on MPS-extensions? It would be great if there was a way to automatically download proper extensions artifact via command line (e.g. `./gradlew downloadExtensions`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me:

`build.gradle` (see https://github.com/Hardella/ide61131/blob/8088fbd9bcc2780f5772856a962fbfe6954b3e50/build.gradle ):

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://projects.itemis.de/nexus/content/repositories/mbeddr' }
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    mpsExtensions
}

dependencies {
    mpsExtensions "de.itemis.mps:extensions:2018.2.+"
}

task resolve_extensions(type: Copy) {
    dependsOn configurations.mpsExtensions
    from {
        configurations.mpsExtensions.resolve().collect { zipTree(it) }
    }
    into "lib"
}
```

Then `./gradlew resolve_extensions` downloads and unpacks `mps-extensions` into `lib/de.itemis.mps.extensions/...` folder.

Then it can be plugged to `MPS` instance via `Preferences` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Project Libraries` / `Global Libraries`.

The following `.mps/libraries.xml` configures the library as `Project Library`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="ProjectLibraryManager">
    <option name="libraries">
      <map>
        <entry key="mps-extensions">
          <value>
            <Library>
              <option name="name" value="mps-extensions" />
              <option name="path" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/lib/de.itemis.mps.extensions" />
            </Library>
          </value>
        </entry>
      </map>
    </option>
  </component>
</project>
```